# How to custom Ionic Local Notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I would like to customize a local notification to my ionic app (something like that)

[image]

I'm trying use the [Local Notification](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications), but I cannot implement some customization like the image above. The action icons does not appears on notification and I would like to click on action button and not close notification.

Follow my code below.

```
public constructor(private platform: Platform, private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {

   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.localNotifications.on('play').subscribe(notification => {
          this.play();
      });
  }

  this.localNotifications.schedule({
     id: 1,
     title: 'App Name - App info here ',
     text: this.musicName + ' - ' + this.artistName,
     led: 'FF0000',
     icon: '../../assets/img/icon1.png',
     actions: [
      {
        id: 'pause',
        title: 'Pause',
        launch: false,
        icon: '../../assets/img/icon2.png'
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: So, which of the customizations aren't working for you?

Comment: the action icons does not appears on notification and I would like to click on action button and not close notification.